# How output distinct number of rows in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query that results in more than 1 million of records in result table.

But I have to use Excel for further processing and it has a limit for such big data.

How can I query e.g. first 500.000 records and then the last?

I use SQL Server 2012.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put `LIMIT 500000` in the end of SELECT clause of your query.

Comment: LIMIT 500000 is a MySQL command, SQL Server does not use it...

Comment: @Sparky, Thanks for pointing, in SQL Server Use `TOP 5000000' just after SELECT CLAUSE of your query.

Comment: You need to define what "first" means. E.g. do you want to order by a specific column, or is there an identity or date/time column that would explicitly order the rows in whatever order you deem to implicitly call "first"?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 has implemented the standard `FETCH/OFFSET` extensions to the `ORDER BY` clause. OFFSET provides the LIMIT/TOP functionality but since it's attached to the ORDER BY clause, you will be forced to provide an explicit order key, thus removing the possibility of getting semi-consistent results using TOP without an explicit ORDER BY.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [OFFSET FETCH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx) clause like this:

```
/* Fetch the first 500k rows */
SELECT col1, col2, ... 
FROM TheTable 
ORDER BY Col1 OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 500000 ROWS ONLY;

/* Fetch the next 500k rows */
SELECT col1, col2, ... 
FROM TheTable 
ORDER BY Col1 OFFSET 500000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 500000 ROWS ONLY;
```

You will have to trim the values used for offset and fetch next to suit the number of rows you want to limit each query by and add extra fetch queries if you need to fetch more than the 1 million in my example.

Comment: Interesting clause. Should I use ASC or DESC before OFFSET clause?

Comment: @user3266538 That would depend on how you want the data sorted, but you do have to order it somehow to use OFFSET.

Comment: Actually I have two columns for ORDER BY: name it date and number.

Comment: So is it correct to use:
ORDER BY Col1, Col2 ASC OFFSET 500000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 500000 ROWS ONLY;
?

Comment: @user3266538 The `Col1, Col2` was only examples, you have to replace them with your actual column names.

Comment: Sure I've meant that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
select TOP 500000 * from table order by id  -- to get the first half..
```

The bottom half requires knowing how they are ordered..   Assume ID is an ordering field

```
select * from
 (select top 500000 * from table order by id DESC) xx
order by xx.id
```

Comment: Getting "the top half" requires knowing how they are ordered too. `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is meaningless, because you are telling SQL Server "I don't care how you order them" and this means you could get a different set of 500K rows every time you run it (or the same set in a different order).

Comment: Thanks Aaron, knew that, but forgot to put it in.   Appreciate you pointing it out...

Answer (score -3):

`SELECT TOP 500000 * FROM table_name`

If you want to get the bottom-most values in the table, do an `ORDER BY column_name ASC` or `DESC`

Comment: How do you feel this gets the "first" 500000 rows?

Comment: It will return the first 500,000 records in the database. They may be ordered or unordered, but it will still return the top 500,000. Which "first" rows are returned will depend on how the table is ordered, or if/how he ordered the table with an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: That's the thing though, without an ORDER BY there is no such thing as "first" - a table, by definition, is *an unordered bag of rows*. You may think that you are getting some magical default or clustered index ordering every time, but I assure you that this is coincidence and, without explicitly telling SQL Server how to determine TOP, it can change.

Comment: Read my comment again...I explicitly stated that they need to use an ORDER BY clause to specify which rows are returned. I never made any claim that they "are getting some magical default or clustered index." The table could be unordered (in which case they would use ORDER BY), or it could be ordered by an identity...

Comment: Your *answer* needs to state that they need an ORDER BY to return the same TOP in a repeatable way (or in a predictable way at all, really). The comments are rarely read and could disappear at any time.